# Вывод из Exel в сообщение telegram Python

Tags: python, парсер, telegram, telebot, python-telegram-bot

Брацы, помогите, всю голову сломал, есть exel файл в нем 5 столбцов и всегда разное количество строк, python его парсит и должен отправить сообщение телеграмм, то что он спарсил, но отправляет только последнюю строку, вот пример кода:

```py
def parser(book):
    sheet = book['Лист 1']
    max_rows = sheet.max_row
    for i in range(2, max_rows + 1):
        addres = sheet.cell(row=i, column=1).value
        fio = sheet.cell(row=i, column=2).value
        tel = sheet.cell(row=i, column=3).value
        date1 = sheet.cell(row=i, column=4).value
        time = sheet.cell(row=i, column=5).value
        if not addres:
            continue
        print("Сегодня по адресу" + addres + "сотрудник " + fio, date1)


cells_of_book = str(parser(book))
print(cells_of_book)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def jobs(message):
    if message.text.lower() in "1":
        bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=cells_of_book)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat_id, "не так кнопка")
```

Comment: Функция `parser` ничего не возвращает при этом, используется так как будто возвращает (`cells_of_book = str(parser(book))`)

Comment: Да я понимаю, что чего-то не понимаю, если использовать print(1,2,3,) то я вижу всю информацию, но не могу передать ее в сообщение...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы вернуть значение из функции, нужно использовать оператор `return` либо `yield` (если генератор):

```py
def parser(book):
    sheet = book['Лист 1']
    max_rows = sheet.max_row
    for i in range(2, max_rows + 1):
        addres = sheet.cell(row=i, column=1).value
        fio = sheet.cell(row=i, column=2).value
        tel = sheet.cell(row=i, column=3).value
        date1 = sheet.cell(row=i, column=4).value
        time = sheet.cell(row=i, column=5).value
        if not addres:
            continue
        yield addres, fio, tel, date1, time  # Возвращаем информацию о сотруднике
        print("Сегодня по адресу" + addres + "сотрудник " + fio, date1)


# Проходим по функции в цикле получая информацию из yield
cells_of_book = "\n".join([f"Сегодня по адресу {worker[0]}"
                           f" сотрудник {worker[1]} {worker[3]}" for worker in parser(book)])
print(cells_of_book)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def jobs(message):
    if message.text.lower() in "1":
        bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=cells_of_book)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat_id, "не так кнопка")
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе, добрый человек.